# mixin vs plugin. What to choose?

Tags: plugins, extjs, extjs4, mixins

Let's assume I have defined several new components -`MyComponent1`, `MyComponent2`, ..., which extend `Ext.Component`.

Now I wnat to extend all this widgets with the same functionality - I want to add `close` button which would appear at the top-right position of `MyComponentX.el`.

What should I use: `mixin`? `plugin`? or something else?
And in general: `mixin vs plugin`, what is the best practise?

Comment: Mixin is inheritance but plugin are composition.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I like to think about it as -

`mixin` is what you use to achieve 'multiple inheritence'

`plugin` is what you use to enhance an existing component. plugin's lifecycle is managed by the component. (no lifecycle managemen for mixin. think of mixin as base class equivalent)

Comment: Thank you for answer. So, which do you think is the best choice for my close-button example?

Comment: I've got it. The best choice would be `plugin` as I want `to enhance an existing component`. Thanks, again.

Comment: Also, since the OP asked about in general, you can only use plugins on `Ext.Component`s

Answer (score 14):

Mixin properties and functions are injected into the class directly so they are part of the class definition.

plugins are added at the instance level

Answer (score 1):

**Plugins**  will add functionality to the Ext.Component class or the class extending Ext.Component.
Scope of any method in plugin is in plugin itself.

**Mixins** can be used to add functionality to any other class.
mixins methods will be available directly into the class.